# SQL Join then combine columns from the result

Tags: sql, db2

So I have two db2 tables.  One contains work order information like id, requester name, user, description, etc.  Second table that has notes, which is keyed to the id of the other table.  The notes field is a 255 text field (Yeah don't suggest changing it, I have no control over it).  So there could be multiple results, or none, in the note field depending on obviously how many notes there are.

I have a query which fetches the results.  The problem is that I am getting multiple results form the join because there are multiple entries.

So my question is how do I concat/merge the results from the notes table into one field for every result?  Thanks

Code:

```
SELECT 
    p.ABAANB AS WO_NUMBER, 
    p.ABAJTX AS Description, 
    i.AIAKTX as Notes 
FROM 
    htedta.WFABCPP p LEFT JOIN  HTEDTA.WFAICPP i 
    ON i.AIAANB = p.ABAANB 
WHERE 
    p.ABABCD = 'ISST' AND p.ABAFD8 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried LISTAGG

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/listagg?lang=en

It will allow you to merge all those pesky fields that are causing the additional records...  Something like this...

```
SELECT p.ABAANB AS WO_NUMBER, p.ABAJTX AS Description, LISTAGG(i.AIAKTX, ' ') as Notes 
FROM htedta.WFABCPP p 
LEFT JOIN  HTEDTA.WFAICPP i 
    ON i.AIAANB = p.ABAANB 
WHERE p.ABABCD = 'ISST' 
    AND p.ABAFD8 = 0
GROUP BY p.ABAAMB, p.ABAJTX
```

Comment: It appears that LISTAGG isn't part of this SQL.  I get an error saying its not found

Answer (score 0):

What version of DB2 are you on?  If you're using DB2 Linux/Unix/Windows (LUW), then this should work for you:

```
SELECT p.ABAANB AS WO_NUMBER, 
       p.ABAJTX AS Description, 
      ,SUBSTR(
          xmlserialize(
             xmlagg(
                xmltext(
                   concat(',' , TRIM(i.AIAKTX))
                )
             ) AS VARCHAR(4000)
          )
          ,2) AS NOTES
FROM      htedta.WFABCPP p
LEFT JOIN HTEDTA.WFAICPP i 
       ON i.AIAANB = p.ABAANB 
WHERE p.ABABCD = 'ISST'
  AND p.ABAFD8 = 0
GROUP BY p.ABAANB,
         p.ABAJTX
```

Comment: Just noticed you said that `LISTAGG()` was not working for you, and that was added in DB2 LUW 9.7.  However, I believe XML functions have been in since version 9, so this may still work for you.  I guess it depends on which platform and version you're on.  :)

Comment: Hmm well you had double ,, so after I corrected that I am getting that it doesn't like the AS in AS VARCHAR(  `The keyword AS was not expected here.  A syntax error was detected at keyword AS.  The partial list of valid tokens is )`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running DB2 at least 9.7, you should be able to use the XMLAGG function similar to this

```
    WITH CombinedNotes( aiaanb, aiaktx) AS (
      SELECT aiaanb
        , REPLACE( REPLACE( 
              CAST( XML2CLOB(
                  XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT( 
                        NAME 'A'
                      , aiaktx
                  ))
              ) AS VARCHAR( 3000))
            , '<A>',''), '</A>', '')
        FROM Htedta.WfaIcpp)
    SELECT p.ABAANB AS WO_NUMBER, p.ABAJTX AS Description, i.AIAKTX as Notes 
      FROM htedta.WFABCPP p 
        LEFT JOIN  CombinedNotes i 
        ON i.AIAANB = p.ABAANB
      WHERE p.ababcd = 'ISST'
        AND p.abafd8 = 0;
```

If you have an earlier version of DB2, or your login for some reason does not permit the XML functions, you can solve the problem with a recursive query. Both techniques are described in the following blog

http://ibmmainframes.com/about44805.html

Comment: `A syntax error was detected at token 'A'.  Token 'A' is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is )`

Comment: Does this work? SELECT XMLELEMENT( NAME 'A', aiaktx) FROM Htedta.WfaIcpp; -- What version of DB2 are you running with?